# How to write data retrieved from DB into 2D array and how can this be retrieved back in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, perlscript

I tried below for writing data into two dimensional array(array_source) but ended up in single dimensional array(array_source).. Below is code snippet, please review and let me know the ways to write it into 2D array so that it can be .

```
$DBHd = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:host=$host;port=$port;sid=$SID", $user_name, $password);
$DBSth = $DBHd->prepare("SELECT EMP_ID,sal FROM emp");
$DBSth->execute();
my @array_temp;
my @array_source; # Should be 2D array and it should contain both values
my @array_source_in; # Should contain only employee IDS alone

while (my @array= $DBSth->fetchrow_array())
{
    push (@array_source, @array[0,1]);
    push (@array_source_in, @array[0]);
};

 print "Data in source : @array_source";
   print "\n";
 print "Data in input : @array_source_in";
```

Once data is retrieved into array_source how can this be compared with another 2D array and list the matching sets ?

Example :

Array 1 - Source Array
[100 5100,
101 5100,
102 6000,
104 7879,
444 287299,
771 111]

Array 2 - Should be compared against source 
[100 5100,
101 5200,
102 0,
772 800,
104 7879]

Array 3 - This should be the output - Singe dimensional
[100,
104]

Please spare with alignment for above Arrays and consider 1 & 2 as two dimensional and 3 as single dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push (@array_source, @array[0,1]);` should become `push (@array_source, [@array[0,1]]);` - you want to push a new array onto the top-level array.